# Actualizar campo OneToOneField - Djando rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework

Tengo un modelo llamado **worker**

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

El cual tiene una relación de 1 a 1 con el modelo **user** de django
Este es mi serializer:

```
class WorkerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = '__all__'
```

y Este mi **viewset:**

```
@transaction.atomic
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            try:
                instance = self.get_object()
                instance.id = kwargs.get('pk')
                serializer = WorkerSerializer(instance=instance, data=request.data)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    self.perform_update(serializer)
                    return Response({"status": True, "results": "Datos actualizados correctamente"},
                                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except ValidationError as err:
                return Response({"status": False, "error_description": err.detail}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

EL problema que tengo es que al querer actualizar el campo **user** me pide el id del user pero yo quiero actualizar poniendo en el cliente su **username** como puedo hacer esto? y como verifico si ese **worker** ya tiene un **user** asociado?

Comment: No sé si es lo que quieres hacer pero el OneToOneField hará que un usuario solo pueda tener un solo worker, así que no podrás añadir un usuario a 2 worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contesto primero como verificar si un worker ya tiene un user.

Al ser un update con el `self.get_object()` obtienes el objeto directamente así que si hacer un `if instance.user != None:` debe comprobarte si ese campo no está vacío y tratarlo de la forma que quieras.

Contesto la segunda cuestión.

Si lo que quieres es pasar el nombre de tu usuario como parametro puedes hacer la siguiente modificación:

```
@transaction.atomic
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs, nombre):
    with transaction.atomic():
        try:
            instance = User.objects.get(username = nombre)
            serializer = WorkerSerializer(instance=instance, data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                self.perform_update(serializer)
                return Response({"status": True, "results": "Datos actualizados correctamente"},
                                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except ValidationError as err:
            return Response({"status": False, "error_description": err.detail}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Yo te recomendaría trabajar con slugs si lo que quieres es trabajar con los nombres. Aunque para eso vas a tener que realizar modificaciones en el modelo de User, en tu serializer y en tus viewsets.

Answer (score 1):

**Podrias usar algo asi:**

```
obj = Worker.objects.get(pk=10)
obj.name = "nameNew"
obj.code = "codeNew"
obj.nameUser = "userName" #from model User
obj.user.save()#save model User
```

espero te sirva suerte